# How can I implement this Fibonacci algorithm using a generic integer type?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have the following code which, when given a number n, calculates the nth Fibonacci number.

```
pub fn fibonacci(n: i64) -> i64 {
   fib_iter(1, 0, 0, 1, n)
}


fn fib_iter(a: i64, b: i64, p: i64, q: i64, count: i64) -> i64 {
   if count == 0 {
      return b;
   }

   if is_even(count) {
      return fib_iter(a, b, p*p + q*q, 2*p*q + q*q, count / 2);
   }

   fib_iter(b*q + a*q + a*p, b*p + a*q, p, q, count - 1)
}
```

The problem is it only works for i64 while I would like it to be generic, so it works for any integral type.

I tried using the Integer trait from the num crate to make it generic:

```
pub fn fibonacci<T: Integer>(n: T) -> T {
   fib_iter(1, 0, 0, 1, n)
}

fn fib_iter<T: Integer>(a: T, b: T, p: T, q: T, count: T) -> T {
   if count.is_zero() {
      return b;
   }

   if count.is_even() {
      return fib_iter(a, b, p*p + q*q, 2*p*q + q*q, count / 2);
   }

   fib_iter(b*q + a*q + a*p, b*p + a*q, p, q, count - 1)
}
```

But it doesn't like the use of any integer literals, for example:

```
66 |       return fib_iter(a, b, p*p + q*q, 2*p*q + q*q, count / 2);
   |                                         ^ no implementation for `{integer} * T`

...


69 |    fib_iter(b*q + a*q + a*p, b*p + a*q, p, q, count - 1)
   |                                                       ^ expected type parameter `T`, found integer
```

I also tried doing something like the following:

```
let two: T = 2;
```

But same problem.
And same if I try using traits Mul, Div, Add, Sub etc.

Comment: Use the [`one()`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/identities/fn.one.html) function to get the multiplicative identity for `T`. Then `2` is simply `one() + one()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`T::one()`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/trait.One.html#tymethod.one) and [`T::zero()`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/trait.Zero.html#tymethod.zero) to get `1` and `0`. Other numbers can either be worked around (e.g. `2*x` → `x+x`) or obtained from `1` (e.g. `2` is `T::one() + T::one()`). You will also need to add a `T: Copy` bound if you want to be able to reuse the same number more than once:

```
use num::Integer;

pub fn fibonacci<T: Integer + Copy>(n: T) -> T {
   fib_iter(T::one(), T::zero(), T::zero(), T::one(), n)
}

fn fib_iter<T: Integer + Copy>(a: T, b: T, p: T, q: T, count: T) -> T {
   if count.is_zero() {
      return b;
   }

   if count.is_even() {
      return fib_iter(a, b, p*p + q*q, p*q + p*q + q*q, count / (T::one() + T::one()));
   }

   fib_iter(b*q + a*q + a*p, b*p + a*q, p, q, count - T::one())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=edc9402fcf0cdab5c185acfcda8a73f5)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to use `num_traits` to implement this:

```rust
use num_traits::identities::{One, Zero};
use std::cmp::PartialEq;
use std::fmt::{Debug, Display};
use std::ops::Add;
use std::ops::BitAnd;
use std::ops::Mul;
use std::ops::Shl;
use std::ops::Shr;
use std::ops::Sub;

pub fn fibonacci<T>(n: T) -> T
where
    T: Add
        + Mul
        + Sub
        + One
        + Zero
        + Shl
        + Shr
        + Copy
        + Shl<Output = T>
        + Shr<Output = T>
        + PartialEq
        + BitAnd
        + Sub<Output = T>
        + Debug
        + Display,
    <T as Shl>::Output: Add<T>,
    <T as BitAnd>::Output: PartialEq<T>,
{
    fib_iter(T::one(), T::zero(), T::zero(), T::one(), n)
}

fn fib_iter<T>(a: T, b: T, p: T, q: T, count: T) -> T
where
    T: Add
        + Mul
        + One
        + Sub
        + Zero
        + Shl
        + Shr
        + Copy
        + Shl<Output = T>
        + Shr<Output = T>
        + PartialEq
        + BitAnd
        + Sub<Output = T>
        + Debug
        + Display,
    <T as Shl>::Output: Add<T>,
    <T as BitAnd>::Output: PartialEq<T>,
{
    if count == T::zero() {
         return b;
    }


    // If even
    if count & T::one() == T::zero() {
        let p2 = p * p;
        let q2 = q * q;
        let pq_x2 = (p * q) << T::one();
        return fib_iter(a, b, p2 + q2, pq_x2 + q2, count >> T::one());
    }

    let ap = a*p;
    let aq = a*q;
    let bp = b*p;
    let bq = b*q;

    fib_iter(bq + aq + ap, bp + aq, p, q, count - T::one())
}

fn main() {
    eprintln!("{}", fibonacci(100 as u128));
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e7ba51c99765874ddf2847e1e48a15db)

[GIST](https://gist.github.com/e7ba51c99765874ddf2847e1e48a15db)